# Is NestedScrollView still useful from API 26 and above?

Tags: android

I am currently checking my app for any issues with the new Android 12 overscroll animation. And I came across plenty screens which contain a RecyclerView inside a NestedScrollView. Usually like this:

```
<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/constraintLayout_root"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView [...] />

        <TextView [...] />

        <TextView [...] />

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recyclerView_attachment_classifications"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="?marginM"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/textView_categorize_title"
            tools:itemCount="4"
            tools:listitem="@layout/list_item_adm_attachment_classification" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

This causes some problems with the new overscroll animation. Unfortunately, I cannot show you a recording of the animation problem, but let me describe it: When the screen is at the topmost position and the user is scrolling upwards, all views should stretch a little in relation to the drag event. But it does not do that. It only shows this stretch animation for a very short period of time AFTER the user released their thumb from the screen.

---

##### What I have found out so far:

- Setting the RecyclerViews `isScrollContainer` to any value has no impact
- Setting the RecyclerViews `isNestedScrollingEnabled` to any value has no impact
- Setting the RecyclerViews `overScrollMode` to any value has no impact
- The same goes for the NestedScrollView

Ironically, replacing the NestedScrollView with a standard ScrollView solves my issue.

I was unable to replicate the problem in a sample app, so it is relatively safe to say that this issue is somewhere in my apps config and architecture. But since using a ScrollView solves my issue, I wanted to know if a NestedScrollView still has any usefulness on API 26 and above or if NestedScrollView is just for backwards compatibility for apps which support older Android versions as well?

Comment: Nested scroll view is still fine and fully functional (as far as nested scrolling api goes). You should clarify if old overscroll animation worked fine, if that's the case then perhaps it's just a bug in library that will be fixed in the future. Also - is there any difference if you start drag on top of text views rather than recyclerview (since that won't start a nested scrolling event).

Comment: Yes, the old animation works fine. But I don't think it is a bug in the library since it works fine in a sample app. When I set `isNestedScrollingEnabled` to false on my RecyclerView then the RecyclerViews animation works fine but it does not fix the problem on the NestedScrollView.

Comment: what sample app do you have in mind? does it have recyclerview inside nestedscrollview as well?

Comment: I made the app myself. It has the exact same view hierarchy as above.

Comment: If exact same view hierarchy works in other app it's a local issue and there's not much I can say other than check your library versions and theme. Maybe you can get by with scroll view if you dont need nested scrolling functionality though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the issues were produced by `NestedScrollView` and fixed by Google in `core-ktx:1.7.0`. I had it on version 1.6.0.